# Material UI autocomplete listbox styling has no impact

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a autocomplete which is has groupBy titles. I am trying to make first group with different  height than the other groups. There is no unique identifier to the ul component hence used the following method to update the styling

```
'& .MuiAutocomplete-listbox > li:nth-of-type(1) > ul': {
        maxHeight: '208px',
        overflowX: 'hidden',
        overflowY: 'auto',
      },
```

This seems to have no impact.

Meanwhile I came across https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32540 which mentions there is a bug but couldn't find any more details about it.

Any leads would be helpful.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Selectively styling the first Group Header can be done by following some of the ideas in the MUI docs.

To demonstrate, the Autocomplete Group By example, [With categories](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#grouped), is used. A [live demo](https://kofeigen.srht.site/so/so-76000646) and [source code](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ekofeigen/autocomplete-groupby) are available.

The MUI example uses the following:

#### 1. options

An array of options where each option object is augmented with a `firstLetter` property:

```
const options = top100Films.map((option) => {
    const firstLetter = option.title[0].toUpperCase();
    return {
        firstLetter: /[0-9]/.test(firstLetter) ? '0-9' : firstLetter,
        ...option,
    };
});
```

#### 2. Autocomplete options property

The Autocomplete options property assigned with an array of options sorted by `firstLetter`.

```
...

<Autocomplete
    id="grouped-demo"
    options={options.sort((a, b) => -b.firstLetter.localeCompare(a.firstLetter))}
    groupBy={(option) => option.firstLetter}

    ...
```

The sorting code (`options.sort((a, b) => -b.firstLetter.localeCompare(a.firstLetter))`) should be executed before the component's `return` statement. The result of the sort should be assigned to a variable (e.g. **sortedOptions**) with component scope. This means that `sortedOptions` should be visible to any function defined within the component that uses Autocomplete. With this change in place, the above code would look like this:

```
...

<Autocomplete
    id="grouped-demo"
    options={ sortedOptions }
    groupBy={(option) => option.firstLetter}

    ...
```

#### 3. Autocomplete renderGroup property

The `renderGroup` property assigned with a component containing a custom GroupHeader component, styled with [styled](https://mui.com/system/styled/).

```
...

renderGroup={(params) => (
    <li key={params.key}>
        <GroupHeader>{params.group}</GroupHeader>
        <GroupItems>{params.children}</GroupItems>
    </li>
)}

...
```

### The First Group Header

With those three ideas in place, the firstLetter property and props from [styled](https://mui.com/system/styled/) can be used to find the First Group Header. Update the GroupHeader component definition in the MUI example as follows:

```
const GroupHeader = styled('div')(({ theme, ...props }) => {
    let isFirstGroup = sortedOptions[0].firstLetter === props.children;

    return {
        position: 'sticky',
        top: '-8px',
        height: isFirstGroup ? '100px' : 'inherit', // Sample adjustment for the First Group.
        padding: '4px 10px',
        color: theme.palette.primary.main,
        backgroundColor:
            theme.palette.mode === 'light'
                ? lighten(theme.palette.primary.light, 0.85)
                : darken(theme.palette.primary.main, 0.8),
    }
});
```

This works because the Autocomplete `renderGroup` callback function has the following signature:

**Signature**:

```
function( params: AutocompleteRenderGroupParams ) => ReactNode
```

Autocomplete passes `params` to the callback. It is an object representing the group to render:

```
let params = {
    group: a string representing a group name
    children: a collection of list items that belong to the group
};
```

`renderGroup` iterates through the array of elements passed to the `groupBy` property to feed the `renderGroup` callback a `param` object that looks something like this (assuming a group name starts with the letter 'A'):

```
param = {
    group: 'A',
    children: ...
};
```

Therefore, the line of code that looks like this: `<GroupHeader>{params.group}</GroupHeader>` is actually rendering this: `<GroupHeader>{'A'}</GroupHeader>`.

Since `'A'` is the child of `GroupHeader` we can use this `let isFirstGroup = sortedOptions[0].firstLetter === props.children;` to extract `'A'` (`props.children === 'A'`) and compare it with the firstLetter property of the first element of the `sortedOptions` array.